# getCount() of CustomArrayAdapter not getting called

Tags: android, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I have written the code for a Custom ArrayAdapter that I am trying to integrate with a AutoCompleteTextView. The code of Adapter looks like this:

```
package com.iincore.msgis.adapters;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import android.widget.TextView;

import com.esri.core.tasks.geocode.LocatorGeocodeResult;
import com.iincore.msgis.offlinenavigation.R;

public class AutoCompleteCustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LocatorGeocodeResult>{

Context         context;
int         layoutResourceId;
List<LocatorGeocodeResult> data;


public AutoCompleteCustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,      List<LocatorGeocodeResult> objects) {
super(context, resource, objects);
this.context = context;
this.layoutResourceId = resource;
this.data = objects;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public LocatorGeocodeResult getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
try {
    if (convertView == null) {
    // inflate the layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
    }

    // LocatorGeocodeResult item based on the position
    LocatorGeocodeResult objectItem = data.get(position);

    // get the TextView and then set the text (item name) and tag (item ID) values
    TextView textViewItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.suggestion_search);
    textViewItem.setText(objectItem.getAddress());
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
    return convertView;
   }



}
```

I am setting this adapter to the `AutoCompleteTextView` in the `onPostExecute()` method of an AsyncTask where I am sending the result (which is a List) as one of the parameter of the AutoCompleteCustomArrayAdapter constructor. `onPostExecute()` method looks like this:

```
  @Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<LocatorGeocodeResult> result) {
super.onPostExecute(result);
AutoCompleteCustomArrayAdapter adapter;
try {
  adapter= new AutoCompleteCustomArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.list_item, result);
    searchBox.setAdapter(adapter);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

Here `context` is the context of MainActivity which is setting the main layout and `searchBox` is the AutoCompleteTextView Object that I had passed from MainActivity.

If I debug my code, I can see the constructor getting called but the getCount() method and getView() method is not getting called.

Comment: are you sure you list is not empty?

Comment: Yes it is not. I can see in my constructor that "data" has 2 entries.

Comment: You are using an AutoCompleteTextView. I thought the adapter is called when you write some text in the input (It's a prediction that shows a drop down list)